Private or internal interface implementation
Framework: .NET 8.0
Unit testing framework NUnit 4.2.2
The objective is to create unit tests for a specific class (ClassA) that relies on another class (ClassB) injected via dependency injection. Both ClassA and ClassB have internal methods. The tests for ClassA should allow mocking or binding (potentially using reflection) of method returns in ClassB.
I started by mocking ClassB with Moq:
Mock<ClassB> _mockClassB
CLassA _classA

[Setup]
public void Setup()
{
    _mockClassB = new Mock<ClassB>();
    _mockClassB.Setup(b => b.method1()).Returns("test_string");
    _classA = new ClassA(_mockClassB);
}

It works, but I need to set the method1 in ClassB to be virtual
I then created an interface for ClassB
public interface IClassB
{
    internal string method1 { get; set;}
}

This way I can keep the old implementation of ClassB (but make method1 as public), and then create a test implementation of ClassB
public ClassBWrapper
{
    public string method1()
    {
        return "test_string";
    }
}

and then in my tests I would use the wrapper instead of the original class:
private object _classA;

[Setup]
public void Setup()
{
    var classAType = typeof(ClassA);
    _classA = Activator.CreateInstance(
            classAType,
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
            binder: null,
            args: new object[] { },
            culture: null
    )

    SetField("_classB", new ClassBWrapper());
}

But here again I'm forced to set the ClassB methods to be public.
What can I do to achieve my requirements?
